Superset with docker - cannot login and login error
I wanted to try Apache Superset so I followed official docs for docker compose: I cloned the repo (step #1) and lunched with step 2 option #1 (i.e. via docker compose up).
Containers build taked some time but it gone well without errors:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS                                       NAMES
ac1889159d43   superset-superset-worker        "/app/docker/docker-…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes (healthy)   8088/tcp                                    superset_worker
fa040944f355   superset-superset               "/app/docker/docker-…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp, :::8088->8088/tcp   superset_app
e27bae857502   superset-superset-worker-beat   "/app/docker/docker-…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes             8088/tcp                                    superset_worker_beat
c17aa731768e   superset-superset-node          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes                                                         superset_node
9b2518c223ad   superset-superset-websocket     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes             0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   superset_websocket
1ee09ede9dc3   postgres:15                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes             127.0.0.1:5432->5432/tcp                    superset_db
014dd226e700   nginx:latest                    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           superset_nginx
e42d9179c9d2   redis:7                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes             127.0.0.1:6379->6379/tcp                    superset_cache


Visited login page at http://localhost:8088 and, following login step used admin:admin as credentials but login failed.
Looked up founding this question that pointed me in the right direction: I logged in the app container and listed existing users with flask fab  list-users and there were none, so I created an admin with flask fab create-admin.
Tried to login again with the new credentials but got this huge json error:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation \"user_attribute\" does not exist\nLINE 2: FROM user_attribute \n             ^\n\n[SQL: SELECT user_attribute.welcome_dashboard_id AS user_attribute_welcome_dashboard_id \nFROM user_attribute \nWHERE user_attribute.user_id = %(user_id_1)s]\n[parameters: {'user_id_1': 1}]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)",
      "error_type": "GENERIC_BACKEND_ERROR",
      "level": "error",
      "extra": {
        "issue_codes": [
          {
            "code": 1011,
            "message": "Issue 1011 - Superset encountered an unexpected error."
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

I don't think I missed any step during installation, don't know what to do now.
I just don't know Superset nor Flask, can anyone help?

Hi @fudo If you have a CustomSSO file in your superset/docker/pythonpath/ check its provider name equals to the SSO config you have mention in superset_config.py file and rebuild the docker image and compose up again and check it should resolve the issue.
